# How can I retrieve the WEP password

Tags: passwords, wep

How can I retrieve the WEP password for the 2wire774 wireless router so I can operate another computer on the network?

Answer (score 2):

If its on windows computer you have already connects to the router [nirsoft wireless key view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) should be able to recover a hashed version. He also has a [router password recovery tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html) that, while not supporting your model explicitly, is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Was this router supplied by your ISP?  Some ISPs will print the WEP code on a sticker on the router.  If its not there, call your ISP, they either know it, or know how to reset your router to default settings to get the default password.

If this router was purchased by you, and you didnt change the password, you should be able to read the manual to get the default password.  Also, the manual will tell how to reset the router to default settings so you can use the default password.

If you ever reset your router to get the default password, you should change the password!

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails:

Googling for a possible answer I came across [a mysterious file](http://myrcurial.com/conferences/cowf-wpa-psk-hash-tables-with-cowpatty-4.0_2006-10-19/cowf-wpa-psk-hash-tables-with-cowpatty_2006-04-29.md5.txt) containing a hash associated with the 2wire774:

3e0cb3c29e6263a9d4ed46d272fe4433

I have no idea what the hash actually is for, but it could the MD5 for the master password.
You would then have to use one of [the many MD5 cracking sites](http://www.stottmeister.com/blog/2009/04/14/how-to-crack-md5-passwords/) in an attempt to recover the password.

BTW, did you try some strings that might be the [default password](http://www.tech-faq.com/2wire-default-password.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Open a web browser and log into the setup page on your router. WEP uses 
"encryption keys", not passwords, and it will be shown in the basic wireless
settings.